# HEAD Causes "Use of undefined constant FULL_BASE_URL" Notice

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I have a CakePHP website that uses the `FULL_BASE_URL` constant in its layout. I noticed errors like this showing up in my "debug.log" file:

```
2013-12-18 16:25:04 Notice: Notice (8): Use of undefined constant FULL_BASE_URL - assumed 'FULL_BASE_URL' in [/var/www/example.com/app/View/Layouts/default-app.ctp, line 11]
Trace:
include - APP/View/Layouts/default-app.ctp, line 11
View::_evaluate() - APP/Lib/cakephp/lib/Cake/View/View.php, line 945
View::_render() - APP/Lib/cakephp/lib/Cake/View/View.php, line 907
View::renderLayout() - APP/Lib/cakephp/lib/Cake/View/View.php, line 535
View::render() - APP/Lib/cakephp/lib/Cake/View/View.php, line 479
Controller::render() - APP/Lib/cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 948
PagesController::display() - APP/Controller/PagesController.php, line 105
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - APP/Lib/cakephp/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 486
Dispatcher::_invoke() - APP/Lib/cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 187
Dispatcher::dispatch() - APP/Lib/cakephp/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 114
```

Looking at the Apache access log, I see that it's caused by this:

`198.252.206.16 - - [18/Dec/2013:16:25:02 -0700] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 200 317 "-" "-"`

The only way I've been able to reproduce this is by using Telnet, like this:

```
telnet example.com 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
[push enter again]
```

What could be causing this? Is it something with my PHP configuration or my Apache configuration or something else?

Comment: @Anubhav 2.4.0 beta. Yes, I know, it's a beta. I'm planning to upgrade at some point. I'm pretty certain that upgrading will not fix it, though. I can report back once I've made the upgrade.

Comment: FULL_BASE_URL Deprecated since version 2.4: This constant is deprecated, you should use Router::fullbaseUrl() instead.

Comment: @Anubhav This is good to know. Thank you! I'm still curious what the cause of my error is, though.

Comment: could you pls share the code of var/www/example.com/app/View/Layouts/default-app.ctp

Answer (score 1):

This is documented at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#FULL_BASE_URL. Please check.